# Voltage is 0.05 when switch is closed

Tags: voltage, switches, pullup

I am new to electronics.  Iam designing a simple circuit where I have to make a digital switch:

[image: Circuit which I have to design]

Here is what I have designed in Proteus:

[image]

There are 2 issues:

1. I want it to output 5V when I *close* the switch but it does opposite. It outputs five when the switch is open.

2. When switch is closed it gives 0.05 volts but I want 0V.

What changes should I make here?

Comment: Not familiar with the software but it should be a DC voltmeter, not AC.

Comment: Interchange SW and R1. That 0.05 suggests you have some ground current along some long wires ... improve the layout to minimise it.

Comment: @BrianDrummond How can I improve the layout.. you mean to shorten it length?

Comment: Learn where the current paths are and how wire resistance affects them. Shortening length is part of it, but so are star earthing and ground planes (you can read about these)

Comment: What is it for? If it is to feed conventional logic, 0.05V is adequate. Depending on the logic family anything below 0.8V is accepted as a logic zero. And anything above ~3.5V is considered a logic one.

Comment: It was switch's resistance which caused 0.05V. 
I changed it to 0.01 to 0.0000001 V and my problem got solved :)

Comment: @Shaheer how was it ever a problem?

Comment: bcs my teacher wanted 0V  :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Swap the resistor and switch
2. Nothing is perfect. Your switch has resistance. Wanting "0V" is like saying you want something to be *exactly* one meter long.

Comment: Thank You! ... Is my circuit according to the circuitry(first picture) I have to implement ?

Comment: If you want 5V when switch closed, it has to be on top and resistor on bottom.